# FileSaver.js saveAs view returns 'undefined' in Chrome 65

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, filesaver.js

I have implemented filesaver in my project before, but since I changed it to ES6 modules, saveAs won't run. From some investigation the `view` within the FileSaver function is returning `undefined`, which causes the function to return and not save my file. Below is how I am calling it. Rasterize and Serialize are functions that create a blob from an svg [which is refactored from here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/saving-svg).

Would the change in `view` be due to the rollup process?

```
       var rasta = await rasterize(chart);
       saveAs(rasta, `chart.png`);

        }
        function rasterize(svg) { // FROM BOSTOCK via Observable modified for use outside of Observable environment
            let resolve, reject;
            const promise = new Promise((y, n) => (resolve = y, reject = n));
            const image = new Image;
            image.onerror = reject;
            image.onload = () => {
                const rect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
                const context = d3.create("canvas").attr("height", rect.height).attr("width", rect.width).node().getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fillRect(0,0,rect.width,rect.height);
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
                context.canvas.toBlob(resolve);
            };
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(serialize(svg));
            return promise;
        }
        function serialize(svg) { // FROM BOSTOCK via Observable modified for use outside of Observable environment
            const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/";
            const xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
            const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

            svg = svg.cloneNode(true);
            svg.setAttributeNS(xmlns, "xmlns", svgns);
            svg.setAttributeNS(xmlns, "xmlns:xlink", xlinkns);
            const serializer = new window.XMLSerializer;
            const string = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
            return new Blob([string], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
        }
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that if I copy paste the original FileSaver file contents into the rollup generated one it works correctly, must be an issue with how the rollup process works.

Comment: You have a backtick after chart.png, is that a typo?

Comment: @AndrewLohr oops yes, supposed to be a string, missed the opening one, fixed.